# Transaction over linked server causing time out

Tags: sql-server-2012, transaction, linked-server

When I execute this query on `[RemoteServer]` linked server, it works just fine:

```
INSERT INTO [RemoteServer].[DbName].[SchemaName].[TableName] VALUES (1, 'bar');
```

but when puting it inside a Transaction it doesn't works anymore:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO [RemoteServer].[DbName].[SchemaName].[TableName] VALUES (1, 'bar');
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
    PRINT 'insert done!';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'insert faild!';
    PRINT 'Error Message: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE();
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

`RPC` and `RPC OUT` are `true` over linked server.

When I execute secound script on my client, after timeout shows following message:

```
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "RemoteServer" returned message "No transaction is active.".

(0 row(s) affected)
Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Windows Firewall blocks DTC packages. To allow it to communicate through Windows Firewall, go to Control Panel > Windows Firewall > Allowed Apps and from list of apps, check `Distributed Transaction Coordinator` for `Private` (or `Public` if needed) network.

If it doesn't works for you check out these solutions:

- [Unable to begin a distributed transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473508/unable-to-begin-a-distributed-transaction)
- [No transaction is active message when accessing Linked Server](http://www.sqldbadiaries.com/2014/09/24/no-transaction-is-active-message-when-accessing-linked-server/)

Comment: Jalal you can mark this as the answer since you solved your own problem.

Comment: @John yes, but accept button needs 48 hours to gets enabled for me :)

Comment: This is perfect! Allowing DTC in Firewall works, however you need not enable "public" network! only domain and private is enough!

Comment: Thank you, updated the answer